# Is it possible to voxelize a volumetric shader using geometry nodes, or create volumes in geometry nodes?

Tags: materials, shaders, volumetrics, geometry-nodes

Using math or signed distance fields, I can create 3D shapes and 3D Fractals using volumes in shaders.

This is convenient and all, but the detail and style is limited, its also very slow, and it doesnt work in eevee.

I want to know if its possible to capture the volumetric data from a material, and convert it to a mesh.

Or, if thats not possible, is it possible to create math-based volumes or 3D fractals in geonodes?

I found this node, but upon plugging in a basic SDF into the density, it went red, so Im assuming it can only take attributes or something?? (I really dont know how to use geonodes)

Ive seen people create points in geonodes based on math before, so I had hope for this, but Im not sure.

[image]